# Calculate difference between first valid value and last valid value in DataFrame per row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find the difference between the first valid value and the last valid value in a DataFrame *per row*.

I have a working code with a for loop and looking for something faster.
Here's an example of what I'm doing currently:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(16).astype(np.float).reshape(4, 4),
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
# Fill some NaN
df.loc[0, ['a', 'd']] = np.nan
df.loc[1, ['c', 'd']] = np.nan
df.loc[2, 'b'] = np.nan
df.loc[3, :] = np.nan

print(df)
#    a    b     c     d
# 0  NaN  1.0   2.0   NaN
# 1  4.0  5.0   NaN   NaN
# 2  8.0  NaN  10.0  11.0
# 3  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN

diffs = pd.Series(index=df.index)
for i in df.index:
    row = df.loc[i]
    min_i = row.first_valid_index()
    max_i = row.last_valid_index()
    if min_i is None or min_i == max_i:  # 0 or 1 valid values
        continue
    diffs[i] = df.loc[i, max_i] - df.loc[i, min_i]

df['diff'] = diffs
print(df)

#    a    b     c     d  diff
# 0  NaN  1.0   2.0   NaN   1.0
# 1  4.0  5.0   NaN   NaN   1.0
# 2  8.0  NaN  10.0  11.0   3.0
# 3  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to [back and forward fill](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) the missing values, and then just compare the first and last rows.

```
df2 = df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).fillna(method='bfill', axis=1)
df['diff'] = df2.ix[:, -1] - df2.ix[:, 0]
```

If you want to do it in one line, without creating a new dataframe:

```
df['diff'] = df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).fillna(method='bfill', axis=1).apply(lambda r: r.d - r.a, axis=1)
```

Comment: ffill and bfill have axis parameters so I guess you can do the same without the transpose. (`df.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)`)

Comment: True @ayhan!  I'm so used to doing it on the other axis that I missed that.  Incorporated into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas making your life easy, one method (first_valid_values()) at a time. Note that you'll have to delete any rows that have *all* NaN values (no point in having these anyways):

For first valid values:

```
a= [df.ix[x,i] for x,i in enumerate(df.apply(lambda row: row.first_valid_index(), axis=1))]
```

For last valid values:

```
b = [df.ix[x,i] for x,i in enumerate(df.apply(lambda row: row[::-1].first_valid_index(), axis=1))]
```

Subtract to get final result:

```
a-b
```